# Java Stream.builder() in Collector null problem

Tags: java, null, stream, builder

The aim is to use a Stream to iterate over an array, filtering/extending values as required and collecting the result in a new Stream.

Trying to use Stream.builder(), as in the following three examples, I'll always get a Stream with the expected Strings, but lots of trailing nulls. In addition, I can't process null elements this way.

I suspect, the internal fixed buffer in `Stream.builder()` is the problem.
Is there a way, to prevent 'trailing' nulls with this approach, without loosing the ability to use null values as Stream elements?

```
String[] whitespaces = new String[] { " ", "\n", "\r", "\t" };
int len = whitespaces.length;
boolean addNulls = false;
int flexBoundary = addNulls ? len : len - 1;

Stream<String> whitespaceNullStringStream = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, flexBoundary)
.mapToObj(idx -> 
  addNulls && idx == flexBoundary 
    ? null 
    : whitespaces[idx])
    
// #1
.collect(Stream::<String>builder, Builder::add, (b1, b2) -> Stream.concat(b1.build(), b2.build())).build();

// #2
//    .collect(Stream::<String>builder, Builder::add, (b1, b2) -> Stream.builder().add(b1).add(b2)).build();

// #3
//    .collect(
//      Collector.of(
//        Stream::<String>builder, 
//        Builder::add, 
//        (b1, b2) -> b1.add(b2.build().reduce(String::concat).get()), 
//        Builder::build
//      )
//    );
```

If I instead use the following, it'll work as expected, except `null` values are converted to Strings, of course, which is not desirable here:

```
.collect(
  Collector.of(
    StringBuilder::new, 
    StringBuilder::append, 
    StringBuilder::append, 
    (sb) -> Stream.of(sb.toString())
  )
)
```

To overcome this, I've used the following approach:

```
Stream<String> stream = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, flexBoundary)
  .mapToObj(idx -> addNulls && idx == flexBoundary ? null : whitespaces[idx])
  .collect(Collector.of(
      ArrayList<String>::new, 
      List::add, 
      (l1, l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2); return l1; }, 
      (list) -> list.stream()
    )
  );
```

But, as described above, I'd like to use the Stream.builder() approach inside a Collector, which works the same.

Comment: Is a Stream.Builder necessary?  It appears you can just write `Stream<String> whitespaceNullStringStream = Stream.of(" ", "\n", "\r", "\t"); if (addNulls) whitespaceNullStringStream = Stream.concat(whitespaceNullStringStream, Stream.of(null));`

Comment: That would likely work, yes, but also breaking fluent API utilization, creating an intermediate var, which I'm trying to avoid, where possible. Also, I was interested in if and how I could achieve that with `Stream.builder()`, somehow limiting the internal buffer length, but it doesn't seem to be possible and nulls seem to be ignored by it.

Comment: Btw. you'd have to use `Stream.ofNullable(null)`, or `Stream.of((T)null)` to avoid NPE.

Comment: Stream.ofNullable does something different which is not what you want.  Stream.ofNullable(null) returns an empty Stream with zero elements in it.  But it is true that `Stream.of((String) null)` is necessary to avoid a compiler warning.  As for an intermediate variable… the cost of an intermediate variable is nothing.  The generated class bytecode will be the same regardless.  And it will be considerably easier for developers (including yourself) to read and maintain in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the stream API will fast-crash when `null` is involved. The things just aren't designed for it.

There are different ideas about what `null` actually means. Reductively, `null` in java means one of 3 things:

- The field was not initialized (`private String hello;` starts out as `null`)
- The array slot was never written to (`new String[10]` starts with 10 `null` values)
- Somebody explicitly used `null`, the keyword.

But that's not too useful. Let's talk semantics. What does it *mean* when an API returns `null` for something, or when you use `null` in some code?

There are different semantic takes on it too:

- It means: Not initialized, not applicable, unexpected, no result.

In this case, **exceptions are good** and anything you could possibly want here *would be wrong*. You can't ask "concatenate this unknown thing to this string". The correct answer is not to silently just skip it. The correct answer is to crash: You can't concatenate an unknown. This is what SQL does with `null` quite consistently, and is a usage of `null` in java that I strongly recommend. It turns nulls downsides into upside: You use `null` when you **want** that exception to occur if any code attempts to interact with the thing the pointer is pointing at (because the idea is: There is no value and the code flow should therefore not even check. If it does, there is a bug, and I would like an exception to occur exactly at the moment the bug is written please!).

In light of your code, if that's your interpretation of `null`, then your code is acting correctly, by throwing an exception.

- It's a sentinel value for something else

This is also common: That `null` is being returned and that this has an explicit semantic meaning, hopefully described in the documentation. If you're ever written this statement:

```
if (x == null || x.isEmpty())
```

it is exceedingly likely you're using this semantic meaning of `null`. After all, that code says: "At least for the purposes of this `if`, there is no difference at all between an empty string and a `null` pointer.

I strongly recommend **you never do this**. It's not necessary (just return an empty string instead!!), and it leads to friction: If you have a method in a `Person` class named `getTitle()` that returns `null` when there is no title, and the project also states that title-less persons should just act as if the title is the empty string (Seems logical), then **this is just wrong**. Don't return `null`. Return `""`. After all, if I call `person.getTitle().length()`, then there **is** a undebatably correct answer to the question posed for someone with no title, and that is `0`.

Sometimes, some system defines specific behaviour that strongly leans towards 'undefined/unknown/unset' behaviour for a given field. For example, let's say the rules are: If the person's `.getStudentId()` call returns a blank string that just means they don't have an ID yet. Then you should also never use `null` then. If a value can represent a thing, then it should represent that thing in only one way. Use `null` if you want exceptions if any code tries to ask *anything at all* about the nature of this value, use an existing value if one exists that does everything you want, and make a sentinel object that throws on certain calls but returns default values for others if you need really fine grained control.

Yes, if you ever write `if (x == null || x.isEmpty())`, that's right: That's a code smell. Code that is highly indicative of suboptimal design. (Exception: Boundary code. If you're receiving objects from a system or from code that isn't under your direct control, then you roll with the punches. But if *their* APIs are bad, you should write an in-between isolating layer that takes their badly designed stuff and translates it to well-designed stuff explicitly. That translation layer is allowed to write `if (x == null || x.isEmpty())`.

It sounds like this is the `null` you want: It sounds like you want the act of appending `null` to the stringbuilder to mean: "Just append nothing, then".

Thus, you want where you now have `null` to act as follows when you append that to a stringbuilder: To do nothing at all to that stringbuilder.

**There is already an object that does what you want**: It's `""`.

Thus:

```java
mapToObj(idx -> 
  addNulls && idx == flexBoundary 
    ? "" 
    : whitespaces[idx])
```

You might want to rename your `addNulls` variable to something else :)

Comment: Pardon, but you seem a littler presumptous here. I'm not trying to create production code here, but something, which generates test data for production code (which is, what the last example will eventually do). No requirement for exceptions here. I just wanted to know, if and how I could achieve the same in a shorter an more concise manner with `Stream.builder()`.

Comment: Another reason is in a `toString()` implementation, with 'legacy' behavior, returning empty for null values.

Comment: What did I presume? I'm explaining what null is for, and that at least the question you ask clearly falls in a certain camp that has a strictly superior strategy to it. It is possible you want this particular `null` to behave semantically differently depending on situation, but the hope was that this answer shows you that's what you are doing (it's not a tenable design model for `null` to mean whatever context demands of it, in that code you did not write obviously can't surmise what you wanted it to do then).

Comment: Well, thanks, I think I get your point.

Comment: Awesome write-up here, shame that it doesn't have more attention. This could totally be converted to a medium.com article to help more developers avoid nonsensical null checks where an exception should have been thrown 3 methods ago.